# The best way to prevent scrolling while mobile navigation is active?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, navigation, scroll

I'm trying to find the best technique for showing a navigation/menu for a mobile site I'm working on. So far all my solutions have flaws, and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. (You may have to reduce browser window size to make the examples work as intended)

**First off, take a look at this "basic" example:** http://audunaas.no/menu/problem.html

*You'll notice the content is still scrollable while the navigation is open. This is confusing and annoying.*

**My first attempt at a fix was to set the body to overflow:hidden and position:fixed whenever the navigation is open. Example here:** *(Had to remove link because maximum 2 links in post)*

*This, however, causes the body to snap back to the top and "forget" its scroll position. This means you are taken back to the top of the page whenever you open the navigation. Not good.*

**Lastly, my best solution so far is one where i put all the page content inside a #scroll-area-div with a fixed position taking up most of the screen, and body scroll set to hidden. Example here:** http://audunaas.no/menu/

This solves most of the problems in the page itself, but breaks the "memory" of the back button. This means whenever you click back in your browser you are taken to the top of the page instead of back to where you were before you decided to click a link. (Mobile safari seems to be the only browser that remembers scroll position on div's aswell as body)

I can't really think of any more solutions to this, except for maybe some sort of javascript. **Does anyone have some experience with similar cases, or any ideas on how to accomplish this?**

**The solution must:**

- Prevent scrolling on page content when navigation is open
- Preserve scroll position on page content when navigation is open
- Remember scroll position on previous page when back-button is used